# Why is the accuracy on the training set dropping in certain iterations of the training?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I'm training using an ANN where i'm using relu activation on all layers except the last one which has a sigmoid activation.

I only have a small amount of data 891 examples. but i'm training using an ANN i've put together using numpy and pandas just as a training exercise.

I've implemented a fuction that would test combinations of layer formations and learning rate that would iterate x amount of times and give me the best average so that i can take a informed guess about the best dimentions and lreaning rate.

However i've been notecing something weird. Some of the iteration have a very low accuracy as shown in the below images.

[image]
[image]

I'm using 'he' weight initalization

```
for l in range(1, L):
    parameters['W' + str(l)] = np.random.randn(layer_dims[l], layer_dims[l-1])*np.sqrt(2/layer_dims[l-1])  # Using he initialization
    parameters['b' + str(l)] = np.zeros((layer_dims[l], 1))
```